# Google Authentication and Mysql

Tags: php, android, mysql, google-oauth

I have used google authentication in my android app and after successful signin, I am storing the credentials in my own database by calling a php script from inside the android app like this

```
String username = acct.getEmail();//Gets Email From Google Auth Api
String link ="http://example.com/storeInDB.php";//PHP script to store        
                                                //Data in mysql database
URL url = new URL(link);
 String data  = URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8") 
+ "=" + URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8");
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();  
OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream()); 
wr.write( data );
```

Problem with this approach is , that anyone without even authenticating can send a post request to that link and can spam me.
What can I do to run the script only when the its called from inside the app or after google authentication?

Answer (score -1):

use some hash strings with your URL then control it on server side.

For example:

On Android site http://example.com/storeInDB.php?hash=ABC123456

then in your PHP file control it like

```
if($_GET["hash"] == "ABC123456"){
//do what do you want
}else{
//access denied
}
```

Comment: How will server side know which hash strings are allowed access and which are not? If i just use some particular hash string ,then spammer can still spam using that hash string value.

Comment: can your spammer know what your link is?

Comment: Well yeah.. he can use wireshark to get the link or decompile the app and see the link in the source code